# Custom column from Joined table unknown

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I created a resourcemodel for my Grid table that contains a custom query that joins 2 table. The `sales_order` and the `sales_payment_transaction` are joined to display all records that has a payment. Below is my query

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            ['spt' => $this->getTable('sales_payment_transaction')],
            'main_table.entity_id = spt.order_id',
            ['spt.created_at as date_paid']
        )
        ->where('main_table.status in ("complete", "processing")')
        ->order('main_table.entity_id DESC');
    
    $this->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see in my custom column I added a new column which is the `spt.created_at` with a name of `date_paid` this new column is use for date filtering. So whenever I filter the order by date is uses the `date_paid` as a parameter. Now when viewing the logs I get this error

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `sales_payment_transaction` AS `spt` 
ON main_table.entity_id = spt.order_id 
WHERE (main_table.status in (\"complete\", \"processing\")) 
   AND (`date_paid` >= '2021-01-03 00:00:00') 
   AND (`date_paid` <= '2021-10-03 22:59:59')

/// Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date_paid' in 'where clause'
```

it seems that it can't recognize the new column. May I know how to properly construct this query?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your quotes are off here:

> ['spt.created_at as date_paid']

should be:

> ['spt.created_at' as 'date_paid']